# Control geoprocessing results related to default data values calculated for null inputs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, file-geodatabase, fields-attributes

I am looking for information on Default data values for the different data types in ArcGIS.  We are running a series of [Overlay Route Events (Linear Referencing)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003m00000009000000) tool operations.  If any of the values from the two input source tables are null then the values in result table are some default data value.  For example for Date field types that have null values in the input tables the values that getting populated in the Overlay operation result are '12/30/1899 0:00:00'.

This is happening in a file geodatabase at ArcMap 10.1 and Windows Server 2008.

Does anyone have information on default data values for data types specifically in reference to geoprocessing?  Any suggestions to get the null values to stay when the Overlay does it's calc?

Field properties say allow null is yes.

I received word from Esri that this is a known bug in the tool **NIM081760**. I'd be interested in hearing of any workarounds.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include more detailed steps for how someone would be able to reproduce the software behaviour you are describing, please?  For example you mention "Linear Referencing Overlay tool operations" but are you using the [Overlay Route Events (Linear Referencing)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003m00000009000000) tool?  Also, you seem to be implying something more generic is astray so perhaps you can describe a simpler way to reproduce it?

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo.  I edited the tool name.  I received word from esri that this is a known bug in the tool #NIM081760.  I'd be interested in hearing of any work arounds.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by the asker:

> I received word from esri that this is a known bug in the tool #NIM081760.

I have not been able to find out anything about the status of NIM081760.